# How to Connect Internet in Zedboard using Linux via SDCard

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, sd-card, fpga

I am working on Zedboard Zynq 7020. I have booted the Linux via SD card through Zedboard. The linux display can be shown onto the monitor via VGA cable. But I cannot connect that linux to internet. Linux is not detecting any wireless network as well. I plugged the one end of LAN cable into Zedboard and other into PC.

I tried to write `ifconfig` into the terminal of linux and I get this message :

```
root@localhost:˜# ifconfig
eth1 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:11:22:33:44:55
inet6 addr: fe80::211:22ff:fe33:4455/64 Scope:Link
```

Here I cannot see this sort of thing:

```
"inet addr:10.1.1.164 Bcast:10.1.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0"
```

As it is essential for detecting the ip address of PC.
Please guide and suggest me the solution.
Thanks

Comment: Please add information about which Linux distribution you are using (or where you downloaded your Linux image to put on the SD Card).

Answer (score 0):

If your network is using IPv4 (which is very likely), the absence of an IPv4 address (like `inet addr:10.1.1.164 Bcast:10.1.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0`) in ifconfig output reveals that your system was unable to acquire an IP address.

On most networks, IP addresses are acquired using DHCP. While usually Linux distributions try to acquire IP addresses automatically via DHCP, this process may have failed (maybe because the Linux distribution is expecting your Ethernet adapter to be named `eth0`). You can try to acquire an IP adress via DHCP manually.

Depending on the Linux distribution installed, one of the following commands may work :

```
   # Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora etc.
   dhclient -v eth1
   # Busybox
   udhcpc -i eth1
```

Comment: I tried to used this command . but nothing works.
further in my PC, there are two ethernet cards. one of them is connected to internet. and on the other card, Zedboard is connected to PC. So inshort two ethernet cards cannot communicate with each other( or the internet on the second ethernet card is not working ).  Dont know what to do in this case . should i configure my pc as a router ?

Comment: Yes, if you want the Zedboard to be able to connect to the Internet with this setup, you need to configure your PC as a router. I was assuming the Zedboard was connected to a home/enterprise network (with a DHCP server and a default gateway). I won't modify my question to add instructions to do this because this is a totally different question.

Comment: OKH. so now i should configure PC as a router and then follow those instructions.